# Masking an image with another image

Tags: delphi, bitmap, masking

Does anyone have an example of how to do some masking with Delphi TImage so I can have one image put on another?

Using 2009

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the Copymode (cmSrcErase,cmSrcCopy,cmSrcAnd,cmSrcInvert) property of the Timage.Canvas, you can find a basic example in this [link](http://www.delphiforfun.org/programs/Delphi_Techniques/maskdrawing.htm).

### [image: picture of clouds] + [image: picture of balloon] = [image: picture of balloon in the sky]

Comment: Good example and an easy method, not sure what speed is like, but in most circumstances that wont matter. +1 :-)

Comment: not a good example hard to follow and why would i want 3 images i want one on another.

Comment: If you just want a shape on top then skip a stage, I suggest that you try the example from start to finish. If you have any questions then ask us. RE

Comment: You asked for masking, you got an example for masking. I guess many people (including me) will rate it a good example. You should consider recalibrating your expectations!

Comment: @Jim this example uses only 2 images, the third image is the final result. the sourcedode included in the page (http://www.delphiforfun.org/programs/Download/MaskDrawSource.zip)   
is very easy to understand.

Comment: none of these are any good can someone give me a better example?

Comment: Explain your problem you have with this answer in greater detail.   We don't read minds.